# How to pass a value/keyword/argument on search box of a website while creating Jmeter Script from the API using Java?

Tags: jmeter

I already created a Jmeter Script from API using Java.
I want to emulate the action where we search a value/keyword/argument in a search box of an eCommerce website.

The below script consists of the following samplers:

1. Load Url(Invoke the sample ecommerce URL)
2. Login(Used AuthManager to use Login Credentials)
3. Search(Search a value/keyword/argument on the search box of the sample website)

Here is my code snippet:

```
package com.blazemeter.demo;

import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Authorization;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.gui.AuthPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class JMeterFromAPI {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      String jmeterHome = "Path of Jmeter Home";
      StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

      //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
      JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
      JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("Path of Jmeter Properties Files");
      JMeterUtils.initLocale();

      // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
      HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

      // HTTP Sampler - Load URL
      HTTPSamplerProxy LoadUrl = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
      LoadUrl.setDomain("www.samplewebsite.com");
      LoadUrl.setPort(80);
      LoadUrl.setPath("/");
      LoadUrl.setMethod("GET");
      LoadUrl.setName("Load Url");
      LoadUrl.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
      LoadUrl.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

      // Create HTTP Authorization Manager
      AuthManager manager = new AuthManager();
      Authorization authorization = new Authorization();
      authorization.setURL("https://www.samplewebsite.com");
      authorization.setUser("sampleusername");
      authorization.setPass("samepassword");
      manager.addAuth(authorization);
      manager.setName(JMeterUtils.getResString("auth_manager_title")); // $NON-NLS-1$
      manager.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, AuthManager.class.getName());
      manager.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, AuthPanel.class.getName());

      // HTTP Sampler - Login
      HTTPSamplerProxy Login = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
      Login.setDomain("www.samplewebsite.com");
      Login.setPort(80);
      Login.setPath("/account/login");
      Login.setMethod("GET");
      Login.setName("Login");
      Login.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
      Login.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

      // HTTP Sampler - Search
      HTTPSamplerProxy Search = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
      Search.setDomain("www.samplewebsite.com"");
      Search.setPort(80);
      Search.setPath("/search?q=mobiles");
      Search.setMethod("GET");
      Search.setName("Search");
      Search.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
      Search.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

      // Loop Controller
      LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
      loopController.setLoops(1);
      loopController.setFirst(true);
      loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
      loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
      loopController.initialize();

      // Thread Group
      ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
      threadGroup.setName("Thread Group");
      threadGroup.setNumThreads(3);
      threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
      threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
      threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
      threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

      // Test Plan
      TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Ecommerce Website");
      testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
      testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
      testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

      // HTTP Request Sampler and Header Manager
      HashTree httpRequestTree = new HashTree();
      httpRequestTree.add(Login, manager);

      // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
      testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
      HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
      threadGroupHashTree.add(LoadUrl);
      threadGroupHashTree.add(httpRequestTree);
      threadGroupHashTree.add(Search);

      SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + "/bin/test.jmx"));

      //Add Summarizer output
      Summariser summer = null;
      String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
      if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
          summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
      }

      // Store Execution Results into a .jtl file
      String logFile = jmeterHome + "/bin/result.jtl";
      ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
      logger.setFilename(logFile);
      testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

      // Run Test Plan
      jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
      jmeter.run();

      System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

So, I want to use the Search Sampler to search a value/keyword/argument for the search box given on the sample website.

Comment: Hi Please refer this page for asking good question which usually get upvoted,which helps in getting good answer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Most probably you won't be able to login using [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) as it is designed to deal with **external** authentication systems like [Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) and [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)). If you need to type your credentials into a [HTML Form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) - most likely you need to use [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and send a [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) request with the credentials.

   For example this code:

   ```
   HTTPSamplerProxy loginSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
   loginSampler.setDomain("example.com");
   loginSampler.setPort(80);
   loginSampler.setPath("/login");
   loginSampler.setMethod("POST");
   loginSampler.setName("Perform Login");
   loginSampler.addArgument("username", "johndoe");
   loginSampler.addArgument("password", "secret");
   loginSampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSamplerProxy.class.getName());
   loginSampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());
   ```

   will result into the following configuration:

   [image: JMeter POST request from API]
2. With regards to search terms - my expectation is that you need to stick to the same approach.

In general creating JMeter test plans using API is not recommended/supported way so I would suggest the following alternative approach:

1. Record your Test Plan skeleton using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
2. Perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter) if required
3. Check if your test is doing what it is supposed to be doing by inspecting requests/responses using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
4. Once your .jmx script is ready use JMeter API to generate exactly the same test plan programatically.

P.S. An easier way of creating JMeter scripts without the GUI is using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool where you can develop a test plan using declarative YAML-based syntax.